# Use older swift version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just got upgraded to Xcode 6.3 and my project stopped compiling because of the changes on Swift 1.2

I was wondering, is there a way I can change my swift version back to 1.1, so I can finish the feature of my app I was working on?

Thanks.

Comment: Use Xcode 6.2 or Swift 1.2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easier to move forward and make the app compile with new version.

It's more likely to be as-> as! or as? which is mostly all the breaking changes for 1.2.

Comment: The 6.3 release notes also mention some additional fix-it and converters.